# How do you capture a group with regex?

Tags: c, regex, posix

I'm trying to extract a string from another using regex.
I'm using the POSIX regex functions (`regcomp, regexec` ...), and I fail at capturing a group ...

For instance, let the pattern be something as simple as `"MAIL FROM:<(.*)>"`
(with `REG_EXTENDED` cflags)

I want to capture everything between '<' and '>'

My problem is that `regmatch_t` gives me the boundaries of the whole pattern (MAIL FROM:<...>) instead of just what's between the parenthesis ...

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance,

**edit: some code**

```
#define SENDER_REGEX "MAIL FROM:<(.*)>"

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  regex_t regex;
  int status;
  regmatch_t pmatch[1];

  if (regcomp(&regex, SENDER_REGEX, REG_ICASE|REG_EXTENDED) != 0)
    printf("regcomp error\n");
  status = regexec(&regex, av[1], 1, pmatch, 0);
  regfree(&regex);
  if (!status)
      printf(  "matched from %d (%c) to %d (%c)\n"
             , pmatch[0].rm_so
             , av[1][pmatch[0].rm_so]
             , pmatch[0].rm_eo
             , av[1][pmatch[0].rm_eo]
            );

  return (0);
}
```

**outputs:**

```
$./a.out "012345MAIL FROM:<abcd>$"
matched from 6 (M) to 22 ($)
```

**solution:**

as RarrRarrRarr said, the indices are  indeed in `pmatch[1].rm_so` and `pmatch[1].rm_eo`
hence `regmatch_t pmatch[1];` becomes `regmatch_t pmatch[2];`
and `regexec(&regex, av[1], 1, pmatch, 0);` becomes `regexec(&regex, av[1], 2, pmatch, 0);`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The 0th element of the pmatch array of regmatch_t structs will contain the boundaries of the whole string matched, as you have noticed. In your example, you are interested in the regmatch_t at index 1, not at index 0, in order to get information about the string matches by the subexpression.

If you need more help, try editing your question to include an actual small code sample so that people can more easily spot the problem.

Answer (score 32):

Here's a code example that demonstrates capturing multiple groups.

You can see that group '0' is the whole match, and subsequent groups are the parts within parentheses.

Note that this will only capture the first match in the source string. [Here's a version that captures multiple groups in multiple matches](https://gist.github.com/3294587).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main ()
{
  char * source = "___ abc123def ___ ghi456 ___";
  char * regexString = "[a-z]*([0-9]+)([a-z]*)";
  size_t maxGroups = 3;

  regex_t regexCompiled;
  regmatch_t groupArray[maxGroups];

  if (regcomp(&regexCompiled, regexString, REG_EXTENDED))
    {
      printf("Could not compile regular expression.\n");
      return 1;
    };

  if (regexec(&regexCompiled, source, maxGroups, groupArray, 0) == 0)
    {
      unsigned int g = 0;
      for (g = 0; g < maxGroups; g++)
        {
          if (groupArray[g].rm_so == (size_t)-1)
            break;  // No more groups

          char sourceCopy[strlen(source) + 1];
          strcpy(sourceCopy, source);
          sourceCopy[groupArray[g].rm_eo] = 0;
          printf("Group %u: [%2u-%2u]: %s\n",
                 g, groupArray[g].rm_so, groupArray[g].rm_eo,
                 sourceCopy + groupArray[g].rm_so);
        }
    }

  regfree(&regexCompiled);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Group 0: [ 4-13]: abc123def
Group 1: [ 7-10]: 123
Group 2: [10-13]: def
```

Comment: `[%2u-%2u]` should be `[%2llu-%2llu]` to avoid warning `format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'regoff_t' (aka 'long long')`